# Add a row with jquery to a Table that's build in a variable

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add some rows and content to a table that's actually build in a variable ?

Sample:

```
//This is the variable i'm talking about
var table = "<table><tr><td>some content</td></tr></table>";

//What i want to do is some like this
$(table).append("<tr><td>some more content</td></tr>");

$("body").append(table);
```

so the output should be like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>some more content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But my samle above doesn't seems to work.

Is it possible to do this in this way?

I know I could add the table first and than add the columns but this is not the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the result of `$(table).append(...)` to a variable, and then append that to the `body`:

```js
var table = "<table><tr><td>some content</td></tr></table>";
var $table = $(table).append("<tr><td>some more content</td></tr>");
$("body").append($table);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: viewing this after years.... yes... this was my true mistake... in my mind (dont know what was wrong with me) `table` was obviously kind of referenced. at least it seems like i thought this way :D

Answer (score 3):

The problem come from the fact you table variable is a string and not an DOM element.
You should do it like that :

```
var table = $('<table>');
table.append('<tr><td>some content</td></tr>')
//What i want to do is some like this
$(table).append("<tr><td>some more content</td></tr>");
$("body").append(table);
```

Here is an example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/50mzw1h8/

Answer (score 3):

Store updated table in a variable, the append the result to body.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //This is the variable i'm talking about
  var table = "<table><tr><td>some content</td></tr></table>";

  //Store result in a variable
  var updatedTable = $(table).append("<tr><td>some more content</td></tr>");

  $("body").append(updatedTable);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: things can be so simple ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var table = "<table><tr><td>Content</td></tr></table>";
 var AppendedTable = jQuery(table).append("<tr><td>Add content</td></tr>");
  jQuery("body").append(AppendedTable);
});
```

Simple and easy :)